# How do I delete a document from Firebase 9 js using a query?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete a doc from 'albums' collection, but only the one, which name property matches props.album.name. I would expect this code to work:

```
  const colRef = collection(firestore, 'albums')
  const q = query(colRef, where('name', '==', props.album.name))
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    deleteDoc(doc)
  })
```

but I get an error instead:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an
> object, got undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I flagged one mistake below, but I'm not sure that is actually where the error message comes from. If it isn't, can you tell us what line/statement the error message points to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looping over a `QuerySnapshot` each `doc` object is a `QueryDocumentSnapshot`, while `deleteDoc` expects a `DocumentReference`. To get from the former to the latter, you can call `.ref` on the snapshot.

So:

```
querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
  deleteDoc(doc.ref)
})
```